Apache Solr 9.7.0 Basic Authentication: "Error 401 Bad credentials" when starting Solr
Configuration Details:
Solr version: 9.7.0
Java version: 17
Operating System: Windows 10
Authentication Method: BasicAuth
Problem:
I am trying to set up Basic Authentication for Apache Solr 9.7.0 on Windows Server 2016, running on Java 17. After enabling authentication, Solr fails to start correctly, and I receive the following error. However, I am still able to log in through the browser using the correct credentials, but in the console (where I issue the command to start Solr), I am receiving this error.
    ERROR: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system?wt=javabin&version=2:     Expected mime type in [application/octet-stream, application/vnd.apache.solr.javabin] but got   text/html.
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <title>Error 401 Bad credentials</title>
    </head>
    <body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Bad credentials</h2>
    <table>
    <tr><th>URI:</th><td>/solr/admin/info/system</td></tr>
    <tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
    <tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Bad credentials</td></tr>
    <tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>

security.json
{ "authentication": { "class": "solr.BasicAuthPlugin", "blockUnknown": true, "credentials": { "solr": "hashed_password" }, "forwardCredentials": false }, "authorization": { "class": "solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin", "user-role": { "solr": "admin" }, "permissions": [ { "name": "security-edit", "role": "admin" } ] } }
Steps I've Taken:

Configured solr.in.cmd with SOLR_AUTH_TYPE=basic and SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS=-Dbasicauth=solr:my_password.

Verified the security.json file for correct credentials.


Note :- However im getting this error still able to login into solr from Browser with correct credentials.
Question:

What am I doing wrong in my Basic Authentication setup for Solr 9.7?
How can I fix the "401 Bad credentials" error when starting Solr?
Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you!

